# VSCode code-workspace file - use environment variables for project home path

Tags: visual-studio-code

Only relevant question with an answer is [vscode multiroot workspace path environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429278/vscode-multiroot-workspace-path-environment-variable) and that answer did not answer the part of the question I have.

### Summary

I'd like to use the same code-workspace file on Windows and Linux (not WSL or mounted container but a physically different host) for defining project paths, but need to set different root project paths for each. Variables as explained for task files don't seem to work in code-workspace file for project locations.

### Detail

Using a .code-workspace file to set project paths like so

```
{
   "name": "foo",
   "path": "literal/path/to/foo-project"
}
```

I'd like to use a .code-workspace file inside a project directory (github repo) and check it out to either windows or linux.

On windows my path to foo-project is

```
D:\projects\foo-project
```

and on linux the path is

```
/home/user/kilroy/projects/foo-project
```

After reading about variables, I thought I could do the following in my project.code-workspace file:

```
{
   "name": "foo",
   "path": "${userHome}/foo-project"
}
```

if I did a symlink between d:\projects and c:\users\kilroy. That does not work, VSCode shows the foo entry but no content. Also does not work if I move foo-project under c:\users\kilroy.

I know I could symlink c:\users\kilroy to /home/kilroy on windows and make the path /home/kilroy/projects but that can mess up search, etc as it will scan both folders, etc.

Wondering if there's some aspect to variables in VSCode code-workspace files I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported in VS Code, however there is an open feature request currently in the development backlog:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/44755

Comment: this answer was already posted before, but it was deleted by the community. I don't believe it should have been deleted. I've voted to undelete the one that got deleted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35358801)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not supported, but there is an open issue ticket tracking a request for it.

See this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/44755